# Indentation of the align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

My code:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Case $1$ :
             \begin{align*}
                         & 2^x-1 =0\\
                         \implies & 2^x = 1 \\
                         \implies & \ln(2^x) = \ln(1)  & \text{ [taking natural  logarithm on both sides]} \\ 
                        \implies & x \ln2 = 0 \\
                        \therefore & \quad x = 0 
             \end{align*}
  \item Case $2$ :
               \begin{align*}
                         & x+3 =0\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = -3 
               \end{align*}
  \item Case $3$ :
             \begin{align*}
                         & x-1 =0\\
                         \therefore &  \quad x = 1 
             \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
```

Now the problem is I don't want to center the equations in the cases 2 and 3. I want to keep them along the red line I have marked on its output.

[image]

How can I prove my code for such desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Case $1$ :
             $ \begin{aligned}[t] \\
                         & 2^x-1 =0\\
                         \implies & 2^x = 1 \\
                         \implies & \ln(2^x) = \ln(1) & \text{ [taking natural logarithm on both sides]} \\
                        \implies & x \ln2 = 0 \\
                        \therefore & \quad x = 0
             \end{aligned} $
  \item Case $2$ :
              $ \begin{aligned}[t] \\
                   \phantom{\implies} & x+3 =0\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = -3
               \end{aligned} $
  \item Case $3$ :
             $ \begin{aligned}[t] \\
                   \phantom{\implies} & x-1 =0\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = 1
             \end{aligned} $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
Does it work with `align` environment?

Comment: Also, I want to put a newline after `Case 1 :`, `Case 2 :`, `Case 3 : `.

Comment: Add a blank line after `Case 1:` , &c. In my opinion, it looks better without the newline.

Comment: Okay, Thank you again!

Comment: like this?
`$ \begin{aligned}[t]
\\
                   \phantom{\implies} & x+3 =0\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = -3
               \end{aligned} $`

Comment: A better idea: insert an empty line at the beginning of each aligned environment , like  this: `\begin{aligned}[t] \\\phantom{\implies} & x+3 =0\\\therefore & \quad x = -3 \end{aligned}`.

Comment: No, it's not looking good. It appears as: 
Case 2 : <newline>
<newline>
Statements. 

I don't want double newlines.

Comment: Kindly give a look at the newline space at the case 1 in my question's output. I wanted that.

Comment: My last comment supposed there was no blank line after `Cas 1:` and the like.

Comment: I've updated  the code and the resulting screenshot. Is it like you want now?

Comment: Thank you @Bernard! 
Also, You were right.  It looks better without the newlines. So I am implementing your previous code.

Comment: Another thing, what is the function of `mathtools` package here? Do I necessarily need to use it here?

Comment: Not here, but I load it systematically for myself in the place of  `amsmath`  as it is a quite useful extension of the latter, and I completed your snippet with one of my preambles.

Comment: Oh, okay! I have used packages `amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts` for maths.

Answer (score 2):

One can use `flalign` to NOT center equations, but you need an extra && in at least one line to take up the right side of the page.  The indentation is achieved using a `minipage`, effectively reducing `\textwidth` to the remaining space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newlength \tempwidth
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{Case $2$ :}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Case $1$ :\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\tempwidth}
             \abovedisplayskip=0pt% or even -\baselineskip
             \begin{flalign*}
                         & 2^x-1 =0 &&\\
                         \implies & 2^x = 1 \\
                         \implies & \ln(2^x) = \ln(1) & \text{ [taking natural logarithm on both sides]} \\
                        \implies & x \ln2 = 0 \\
                        \therefore & \quad x = 0
             \end{flalign*}\end{minipage}
  \item Case $2$ :\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\tempwidth}
             \abovedisplayskip=0pt
             \begin{flalign*}
                   \phantom{\implies} & x+3 =0 &&\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = -3
             \end{flalign*}\end{minipage}
  \item Case $3$ :\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\tempwidth}
             \abovedisplayskip=0pt
             \begin{flalign*}
                   \phantom{\implies} & x-1 =0 &&\\
                         \therefore & \quad x = 1
             \end{flalign*}\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]